# While running command "sudo gem pristine --all" getting error

Tags: linux, rubygems, bundle, redmine, rhel8

Restoring gems to pristine condition...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)
I am using rhel 8.6.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact command you are running as well as the full error message (including the full stack trace).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.